# C++ Why the call is ambigous?

Tags: c++

```
class myClass {
   int arr[100];
public:
    void *get(long i, void* const to) const;
    void *get(long i, bool nog);
    void *tstfn(void* const to) { return get(0L,to); }
};
```

gcc -Wall says:

```
dt.cpp: In member function ‘void* myClass::tstfn(void*)’:
dt.cpp:6:49: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]
dt.cpp:4:9: note: candidate 1: void* myClass::get(long int, void*) const
dt.cpp:5:9: note: candidate 2: void* myClass::get(long int, bool)
```

Comment: What type of argument are you supplying as the second parameter? I ask mainly out of curiosity; I'm unlikely to be much help.

Comment: Thanks to all!
return ((const myClass*const)this)->get(0L,to);
worked.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both function calls require a type conversion:

- calling the `void*` function requires adding a `const` qualifer to `this`
- calling the `bool` function requires converting `to` from `void*` to `bool`.

So, by the overload resolution rules, neither is a "better" match than the other, and the call is considered ambiguous.

Perhaps you can add `const` to the second function; perhaps you could remove it from the first (although I'd prefer not to); perhaps you can do an explicit type conversion of either `this` or `to` to force your preferred override.

Comment: An additional option is just adding a non-`const` overload calling the `const` one, probably an in-class defined inline-function.

Comment: Thanks, but I am rather new to C++ and do not catch, why can't I call const method from not-const one? This is an example, and the tstfn is to be NOT const, while get(long, void*) - const.
And how can I make 'this' const?

Comment: @ВладимирТкачёв You *can* call it, the issue is that there are two equally good choices for `get()` - which one do you want to call? If you had one or the other, the call would be fine. Making `this` const is just `const_cast<const myClass*>(this)`.

Comment: @ВладимирТкачёв: You can call the const method; but, here, it causes an ambiguity since there are two possible function calls, each of which need a type conversion to match your arguments. You can convert it to `const` with `static_cast<myClass const *>(this)`

Comment: Nevertheless I understand the solution and a kind of (very formal) logic behind it, is it not strange behavior? 'this' is an argument of a method, but not only. No?

Comment: @ВладимирТкачёв: `this` is treated as a function argument for the purposes of overload resolution, yes. So type conversions on `this` (i.e. adding const/volatile qualifiers) are included in the criteria for selecting the "best" overload, along with type conversions on the other arguments, giving an ambiguity in this case where both function calls require a type conversion. Whether or not one considers that "strange" is a matter of opinion; the rules are at least consistent here, if rather complicated.

Answer (score 13):

Because `void *get(long i, void* const to)` is `const`.

This means that calling it from `tstfn` (which is non-const) would require qualification conversion for `this` from `myClass*` to `const myClass*`, so calling both functions would require a conversion for the arguments (`this` is treated in the same way as other arguments), so the call is ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

Simply because your `testfn` is a non-const function, which would call the non-const version of `get`. The non-const function `get`, takes `bool` not `const void*`. Had only one `get` function was there (possibly taking `void*` as the second argument, irrespective of its constness), then would be called without ambiguity.

Comment: @Slava It's actually +2

Comment: @Ajay there are 2 correct answers already, your is incorrect.

Comment: I just made it more clear, and I still think original was not incorrect.

Comment: Having only one `get()` would solve issue with ambiguity that's pretty obvious. But your explanation still incorrect. Problem is not there are 2 functions, problem is that both require a type conversion.